# What algorithm does SPICE server use in video stream detection?

Tags: video-streaming

I read the spice server code, and find that the video stream detection code is in server/spice-bitmap-utils.c. func `bitmap_get_graduality_level` will calculate a score, and the GRADUALITY is set based on the score.

So what's the meaning of this score, and what algorithm does it use to calculate this score?

Comment: What does this have to do with openstack?

Comment: I am using openstack with SPICE display.

Comment: Maybe a better tag would be spice?

Comment: There isn't a `spice` tag exist.

Comment: How about something like video streaming? You will never get an answer on this, as it has nothing to do with OpenStack.